# Binding to a list in a class

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp, uwp-xaml

for an application i'm developing im working with bluetooth devices.
each of these devices has a name and several Services. i am trying to show them, and their services programmatically.

to do this i've created a class containing the list of services. when trying to bind however, the list of services seems completely empty.

XAML:

```
public class BluetoothDevices
{
    public string Name{ get; set;}
    //public List<Guid> Services { get; set; }
    public List<string> Services { get; set; }
}
```

XAML:

```
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Width="150" />
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Services}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

c#:

```
        adapter.ScanForBroadcasts(async (IBlePeripheral peripheral) =>
        {
            //List<Guid> services = new List<Guid>();
            List<string> services = new List<string>();

            string devicename = peripheral.Advertisement.DeviceName;
            var _services = peripheral.Advertisement.Services;
            var servicedata = peripheral.Advertisement.ServiceData;
            //services = (_services.ToList());


            await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
            () =>
            {
                services.Add("i am a string ");
                BluetoothDevices.Add(new BluetoothDevices { Name = devicename, Services = services });
            });
            //BluetoothDevices = new ObservableCollection<BluetoothDevices>(BluetoothDevices.Distinct());
        }, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
```

Comment: Use `ObservableCollection` instead of `List`. `List` doesn't notify anybody when you add items to it, so you won't see anything that was added after the UI was created. `ObservableCollection` does. If that doesn't fix it, you're probably binding it wrong. Is `BluetoothDevices` your viewmodel or something else? It should be implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Also note degant's correct suggestion.

Comment: I figured that wouldn't be the problem as i'm creating the list, then adding the item to the observablecollection. 
EDIT:
even with nested observablecollections it doesnt work.

Comment: What observablecollection? What does "nested observablecollections" mean? Are you saying that `BluetoothDevices` is an ObservableCollection? By the way, it's always safe to assume that at least one of your assumptions about the cause of the issue is wrong -- otherwise you wouldn't be here asking for help.

Comment: Anyway, if you leave out important details, people have to guess at what to rule out. If `BluetoothDevices` is an `ObservableCollection` and the `ListView` binds to it correctly, show us that code, because when somebody says "empty listview", the first question is always "how are you populating it?"

Comment: with nested i meant one inside another, as the observablecollection is of type <BluetoothDevices> and the list is part of that type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the binding like this. I am assuming you want this inner `ListView` to show all the services available. For this you must bind the `Services` list to the `ItemsSource` of your `ListView` so that each item in the list is an element in the `ListView`. By using `Text="{Binding}"`, the text block is bound directly to each instance of the collection (in this case the `string` is directly bound to the `Text`). So modify your bindings like this:

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Services}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
             </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:** Added explanation for binding

Comment: That does it, i had previously tried to bind it to Services itself, which didn't work. if i understand correctly, binding in this refers to the object bound as the itemssource?

Comment: Yes `Services` must be bound to the `ItemsSource` for the `ListView` to work correctly. I also added some explanation in the answer

Comment: thanks a lot, the MSDN documentation wasn't very clear on this

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help! :)